# Why am I getting a MySQL foreign key insert constraint violation in a transaction for a single self-referenced table?

Tags: mysql, transactions, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a self-referenced table like:

> The table schema for "ClassGroup" is:
>   Id String,     Primary key
>   Name String,
>   ParentClassGroup String, Foreign key (refers to the "id" in this table itself)

The following transaction will succeed as expected:

> SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
>   start TRANSACTION;
>   INSERT INTO CLASSGROUP(x_id, x_name, x_parentclassgroup_x_id) values("id1","cg1", null);
>   INSERT INTO CLASSGROUP(x_id, x_name, x_parentclassgroup_x_id) values("id2","cg2", "id1");
>   INSERT INTO CLASSGROUP(x_id, x_name, x_parentclassgroup_x_id) values("id3","cg3", null);
>   commit;

But the following transaction will fail:

> SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
>   start TRANSACTION;
>   INSERT INTO CLASSGROUP(x_id, x_name, x_parentclassgroup_x_id) values("id2","cg2", "id1");
>   INSERT INTO CLASSGROUP(x_id, x_name, x_parentclassgroup_x_id) values("id1","cg1", null);
>   INSERT INTO CLASSGROUP(x_id, x_name, x_parentclassgroup_x_id) values("id3","cg3", null);
>   commit;

The error log:

> 0 08:14:29 INSERT INTO CLASSGROUP(x_id, x_name, x_parentclassgroup_x_id,x_talend_timestamp) values("id2","cg2", "id1", 123) Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (hier_master.classgroup, CONSTRAINT FKC0C64078BC2ACBF FOREIGN KEY (x_parentclassgroup_x_id) REFERENCES classgroup (x_id))

My question is:
MySQL Server is not smart enough to know that the second insertion should be done before the first one because record with "id2" refers to the record with "id1"? Is the failure expected due to the wrong insertion order? What about transaction in other database like Oracle?
Thanks a lot for your insights and help!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. In all RDBMS(Oracle, MySQL, H2) as I tested, no RDBMs would reorder the sql statments in a transaction based on data dependency, rdbms will execute each sql statement in the order they are feeded in the trasaction by users. So it's your responsibility to make sure data dependency is resolved by correctly ordering the sql insertion statments in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a provision for this in MySQL called deferred constraint checking.

What it does is, it does all the manipulations to the table as performed by a user and then checks for constraint violations as opposed to the normal way of checking constraint violation after each insert statement.

I don't know the exact syntax of deferred constraint checking but I am sure you can easily find it over the internet.
I hope this helps!
:)

Comment: Ohh and sorry, I got no idea about Oracle because I am just a beginner in the mysql and databases field. :)